# SSRS SQL - time parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I was able to set a date parameter in my SSRS using the below code and making it a Date/Time data type in SSRS.

`and LAB_ORD.Final_Date between @StartDate and @EndDate`

[image]

The problem I am having is that I want to be able to have the StartDate pull from 00:00AM and the EndDate to pull until 11:59pm of the selected days... Right now it is pulling between those dates, and at inconsistent times.

The "Final Date" is in the format of 'Mar 14 2020 10:17AM'

Comment: Are you setting a default on those parameters or are you letting the user pick them at runtime?

Comment: I usually cast the DateTime as a date in the WHERE - `and CAST(LAB_ORD.Final_Date AS DATE) between @StartDate and @EndDate`. Saves the trouble of adding the time to the END and worrying about those 11:59:59.996 updates.